# velocity confusion

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, physics

A velocity encompasses both speed and direction in a single vector. I'm a little bit confused about how to separate the two.

I have 2 creatures. The first is located at position (x1, y1). The second is located at (x2, y2).

I would like the first creature to move towards the second creature, so I get the vector from creature1 to creature2 as so:

```
velocity = (x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
```

Then I normalize the vector using the distance between the 2 points like so:

```
velocity.x = velocity.x / distance;
velocity.y = velocity.y / distance;
```

If I use this as my velocity, the creature will move in the correct direction but it will be moving too fast. How can I control the speed of the creature without changing the direction? I would like for creature1 to move in the direction of creature2 at a constant speed which I choose.

Comment: The speed is the norm (length) of the velocity vector.

Comment: To increase or decrease the speed, multiply each component of the velocity by a positive number $a$. You'll reduce the speed for $0<a<1$ and increase the speed for $a>1$.

Comment: Thanks, David. That information combined with a typo fix solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have written is not strictly speaking the velocity vector,  but rather the displacement vector: $d=(x_2-x_1, y_2-y_2)$.  If you normalize this, though, you'll get a unit vector in the same direction as the velocity vector:

$\ \ \ v=(v_1,v_2 )$ where $v_1={x_2-x_1\over\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2} }$ and $v_2={y_2-y_1\over\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2} }$.

You can impose any speed you wish by multiplying $v$ by a positive constant: $v_a=(av_1,av_2)$ will still have the direction of $v$, but the speed  now is $a$.

Answer (score 0):

In one dimension, the *average velocity* as an idealized object (or idealized reference point on an object) moves from $x_1$ to $x_2$ between timepoints $t_1$ and $t_2$ is
$$
v=\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}=\frac{x_2-x_1}{t_2-t_1}
\,.
$$
You just need to generalize this to two dimensions:
$$
v=\frac{\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2}}{\Delta t}
=\frac{\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}}{t_2-t_1}
$$
As a *vector*, you could write
$$\vec{x_1}=(x_1,y_1)$$
$$\vec{x_2}=(x_2,y_2)$$
$$\vec{\Delta x}=\vec{x_2}-\vec{x_1}=(x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1)$$
and the average velocity vector would be the
componentwise one-dimensional formula we started with above:
$$
\vec{v}=\frac{\vec{\Delta x}}{\Delta t}
=\left(\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t},\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta t}\right)
$$
The average *speed* would be the norm of this vector:
$$
|\vec{v}|=\frac{|\vec{\Delta x}|}{|\Delta t|}
=\left|\left(\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t},\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta t}\right)\right|
=\sqrt{
\left(\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}\right)^2
+\left(\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}\right)^2}
=\frac{\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2}}{|\Delta t|}
$$